# OpenCv Compiling With Code::Blocks on Windows

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, codeblocks

I want to use the opencv library with code::blocks.

I am using windows 7 Pro x86 os. I've installed Code::Blocks 13.12.

I've download and extract opencv library on my disk (C:\Opencv242).

I also have opencv 2.4.9 and some other versions.

I already tried so much method. I never compilied succesfully. Every time it get me some errors.

Like;

for this code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

Mat img = imread("C:\\PROJELER\\Software Projects\\Opencv\\pic.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("MyWindow", img);

waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

It getting theese errors to me;

> ||=== Build: Debug in Opencv (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':| C:\PROJELER\Software
>   Projects\Opencv\main.cpp|12|undefined reference to`
>   cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'| C:\PROJELER\Software
>   Projects\Opencv\main.cpp|14|undefined reference to
>   `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'| C:\PROJELER\Software
>   Projects\Opencv\main.cpp|15|undefined reference to`
>   cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'| C:\PROJELER\Software
>   Projects\Opencv\main.cpp|15|undefined reference to
>   `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'|
>   C:\PROJELER\Software Projects\Opencv\main.cpp|17|undefined reference
>   to`cv::waitKey(int)'| obj\Debug\main.o||In function `ZN2cv3MatD1Ev':|
>   C:\PROJELER\Software
>   Projects\Opencv\..\..\..\Opencv242\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp|278|undefined
>   reference to`cv::fastFree(void*)'| obj\Debug\main.o||In function
>   `ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv':| C:\PROJELER\Software
>   Projects\Opencv\..\..\..\Opencv242\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp|367|undefined
>   reference to`cv::Mat::deallocate()'| ||=== Build failed: 7 error(s),
>   0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|

I want to clean install.But i dont know how.

I followed so many person.Last I tried this one;

http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/

I still cant compiling.

Can any one help me how is this?Which way is the right one?

Thanks all of you.

I hope some one help and somehow this problem is solve.

Comment: By the way i forget some details.So sorry..

I've added system path opencv\build\x86\bin, c:\mingw\bin,cmake\bin,codeblocks and some others.

Comment: there were a lot of problems with prebuilt mingw libs due to the fact that you have to use *exactly* the same mingw setup used when compiling the libs, so they ditched that lately. do yourself a favour and build them from the 2.4.9 src using cmake.

Comment: Thank you. I ve tried that before. I will try it again. But I don't beleive it will works. I will let you know the result

Comment: honestly, the whole mingw thing involves a certain amount of masochism.

Comment: I am sorry what is that mean berak? By the way ive tried make the opencv249 with cmake. And i followed zahidhasan tutorial about how onstall win 7 x64 codeblocks. But still dosnt work. Still dosnt compiled. Can any one help????

Comment: ah, ignore, i was only trying to pull your leg there. mingw is quite a 2nd class citizen on windows. if you decide to use it, you will have to invest significantly more work, than with vs express.

Comment: I have to compile this with codeblocks and i am not much know english please use simple english pusyblity. Thank you

Comment: ok, ok. best wishes then, and sorry for the confusion ;)

Comment: Why is that?  What just happend?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add linker directory path. For more info, check this link:
[OpenCV Codeblocks Setup](http://opensourcecollection.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-setup-codeblocks-for-opencv.html)

Comment: that answer is linking to a 4-year old blog. it's no more relevant, even wrong today.

Comment: I cant access that web site.?